# How to disable InnoDB in Mysql 5.7.13?

Tags: mysql, innodb, ubuntu-16.04

I recently upgraded my low-ram VPS from Ubuntu Server 14.04 to Ubuntu Server 16.04.
I never use InnoDB, so I always disable it by config file.
Unfortunately, I can't manage to do it after server upgrade, and mysql process is "eating" much more RAM.

I tried this config:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
innodb=OFF
loose-innodb-trx=0
loose-innodb-locks=0
loose-innodb-lock-waits=0
loose-innodb-cmp=0
loose-innodb-cmp-per-index=0
loose-innodb-cmp-per-index-reset=0
loose-innodb-cmp-reset=0
loose-innodb-cmpmem=0
loose-innodb-cmpmem-reset=0
loose-innodb-buffer-page=0
loose-innodb-buffer-page-lru=0
loose-innodb-buffer-pool-stats=0
loose-innodb-metrics=0
loose-innodb-ft-default-stopword=0
loose-innodb-ft-inserted=0
loose-innodb-ft-deleted=0
loose-innodb-ft-being-deleted=0
loose-innodb-ft-config=0
loose-innodb-ft-index-cache=0
loose-innodb-ft-index-table=0
loose-innodb-sys-tables=0
loose-innodb-sys-tablestats=0
loose-innodb-sys-indexes=0
loose-innodb-sys-columns=0
loose-innodb-sys-fields=0
loose-innodb-sys-foreign=0
loose-innodb-sys-foreign-cols=0
skip-innodb
ignore-builtin-innodb
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
default-tmp-storage-engine=MyISAM
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci; SET NAMES utf8;' 
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci 
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Unfortunately InnoDB still works, I can for example create InnoDB tables by Mysql Workbench. Am I missing something?

```
root@:~# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

show engines:

```
PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA  YES Performance Schema  NO  NO  NO
CSV YES CSV storage engine  NO  NO  NO
MRG_MYISAM  YES Collection of identical MyISAM tables   NO  NO  NO
BLACKHOLE   YES /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears)  NO  NO  NO
InnoDB  YES Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys  YES YES YES
MEMORY  YES Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables   NO  NO  NO
ARCHIVE YES Archive storage engine  NO  NO  NO
MyISAM  DEFAULT MyISAM storage engine   NO  NO  NO
FEDERATED   NO  Federated MySQL storage engine
```

Comment: How tiny is your RAM?  256MB is sufficient to have InnoDB turned on.  The _cost_ for that much RAM is about 1 dollar or Euro.  The rental on that should not be much; is it?

Comment: My VPS has 1GB RAM, and Mysql uses ~50% of it. I don't need more RAM at the moment, but still it seems to be wasted, since before server upgrade I was able to configure mysql to use only ~15% of RAM with when I disabled InnoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL documentation says:

> "As of MySQL 5.7.5, the InnoDB storage engine can no longer be
>   disabled, and the --innodb=OFF and --skip-innodb options are
>   deprecated and have no effect. Their use results in a warning. These
>   options will be removed in a future MySQL release."

[15.14 InnoDB Startup Options and System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_innodb)

Comment: Thank you for this information. I simply moved to MariaDB yesterday as I use only basic mysql queries :)